# scala semantic highlighting based on sbt analysis info

Tags: scala, sbt, syntax-highlighting, semantics

I'm diving into sbt now and have noticed that there are plenty information about building project extracted and stored inside analysis.apis. It should be enough for semantic highlighting and basic refactoring.

Is there any plugin/library that utilized extracted info for highlighting scala source files?

I'm searching for something like the pygments library that may be utilized in many ways for generating files and for coloring in some real-time editor.

Comment: You may want to look into scala presentation compiler.

Comment: It used by sbt for doing all work as I have catched. So why you should do this work twice? If you already have continuous iterative compilation done by sbt, why not use gained output?